# Problema no aquivo style.xml Android Stúdio

Tags: android-studio

Com essas últimas atualizações do Android Studio estou estranhando no arquivo styles.xml do projeto que o theme está em vermelho, como pode ser observado na imagem abaixo:

[image: Erro no style.xml do android studio]

**CÓDIGO**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButton" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/button_disabled</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Fullscreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Até quando eu gero um novo projeto no Android Studio o arquivo style.xml fica dessa forma.

Alguém sabe se há algum bug ou como corrigir isso?

A versão do Android Studio que tenho aqui é 3.1.1.

Comment: Recomendo que [**leia isso**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/28595)

Comment: Creio que no caso em tela não se aplica ao problema ocasionado com post de uma imagem apenas para mostrar o possível erro no código. O intuito da imagem é mostrar a marcação na cor vermelha que o Android Studio está fazendo, simplesmente isto. Agora, se a questão de não postar o código irrita muita gente, não tem problema, eu posto o código!

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734990/2556111)

Comment: @ramaral infelizmente não funcionou. Eu apaguei inteiramente as pastas .gradle e .idea do projeto e reconstruí o projeto e o problema não foi resolvido. Mesmo que eu gere um novo projeto do zero no Android Studio o arquivo style.xml fica da forma que aparece na imagem que postei. Portanto, creio que a questão seja externa ao projeto.

Comment: Vou corrigir aqui minha informação anterior. No momento em que apaguei as pastas .gradle e .idea e reconstrui o aplicativo e fiz as sincronizações necessárias não houve correção no arquivo style.xml. Porém mais tarde ao religar o computador e abrir o projeto novamente no Android Studio o problema foi resolvido. Portanto, aos que tiverem o mesmo problema que o meu, vale a dica passada no link do Ramaral.