# Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme' no arquivo styles.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

Está dando a seguinte mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Android Studio 3.2.1

build.gradle (Project:xxx) dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2' }

Tentei o seguinte:

1) Excluí o diretório .gradle do projeto
2) Build -> clean project
3) Build -> rebuild project   (sem sucesso).

A versão do Android Studio tem que ser a mesma do build.gradle? Se sim, como faço para atualizar?

Antecipadamente agradeço

Comment: Relacionado: [Problema no aquivo style.xml Android Stúdio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/291784/2541)

Comment: Consegui resolver desinstalando e reinstalando a biblioteca de suporte: SDK Manager -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools -> Support Repository